# best way to get the data from database

Tags: android, xml, database, local-storage

I was designing the classified app in android which takes the data from the db hosted at run time. I have designed it and it is working fine but it is very slow as application has to fetch the data from the server and which take much time. I want to reduce the time by some way that user get the data immediate and also can get the data offline with out internet.

Can any one suggest me the best way for store the data in the mobile app or any other way? 
can i create a xml and store it on user mobile?

Please let me know.

thanks in advance.
itin

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do this by [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Another way is to use a framework like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com), an Object Relational Mapping.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two good methods . Fist one ;use store procedures ,triggers and functions to get data from database .Second method get data by using service like json do not use xml(soap).